# Reinstall package in CentOS

Tags: centos, package-management

I am trying to install a perl package and getting the following dependencies error:

```
[user@localhost Downloads]$ rpm -Uvh ImageMagick-6.8.4-9.i386.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    libltdl.so.3 is needed by ImageMagick-6.8.4-4.i386
```

In order to solve it, I have tried to install the missing package but it seems that it already exists:

```
[Evgeny@localhost Downloads]$ sudo yum install libltdl.so.3
...
No package libltdl.so.3 available.
```

Then I have tried to use `yum` with `reinstall` option but I got another error:

```
[Evgeny@localhost Downloads]$ sudo yum reinstall libltdl.so.3
...
No Match for argument: libltdl.so.3
Error: Nothing to do
```

What's the problem here? Should I completely uninstall current `libltdl.so.3` package and the install it form scratch? Or maybe there is a different issue?

Comment: libltdl.so.3 is the name of the file you're wanting to get. You have to give yum package names to install to figure out what package provides a particular file:"yum whatprovides */libltdl.so.3"

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the package "libtool-ltdl" not "libltdl.so.3" This is only a shared library that is a part of the package mentioned above.

```
yum install "libtool-ltdl"
rpm -Uvh ImageMagick-6.8.4-9.i386.rpm
```

should get it working.

here are all of the results for packages that contain the file libltdl.so.3 for centos

```
You have chosen search in content of rpms.
Display 1 - 38 hits of 38. Search took 0.02 seconds.
1
1




Search results for libltdl.so.3 :
CentOS 5    ftp.centos.org/5.9/os/x86_64/CentOS/libtool-ltdl-1.5.22-7.el5_4.x86_64.rpm
CentOS 5    ftp.centos.org/5.9/os/x86_64/CentOS/libtool-ltdl-1.5.22-7.el5_4.i386.rpm
CentOS 5    ftp.centos.org/5.9/os/i386/CentOS/libtool-ltdl-1.5.22-7.el5_4.i386.rpm
CentOS Other    yum.trixbox.org/centos/4/RPMS/libtool-libs-1.5.6-4.EL4.1.c4.4.i386.rpm
Other   ftp.rpmhelp.net/pub/releases/1.0-CURRENT/i586/RPMS/libltdl3-1.4.3-9sls.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/g/gw/gwmos/GW Monitor Community Edition/5.0.5-208/groundwork-monitor-os-5.0.5-208.sles9.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/g/gw/gwmos/GW Monitor Community Edition/5.0.5-208/groundwork-monitor-os-5.0.5-208.sles10.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/g/gw/gwmos/OldFiles/groundwork-monitor-os-4.5-M1.31a.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/m/ma/mapifier/OldFiles/groundwork-monitor-os-4.5-M1.31.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/g/gw/gwmos/GW Monitor Community Edition/4.5.11/groundwork-monitor-os-4.5-11.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ar/arp2.berlios/gg-libtool-1.4.2-2.i386.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ar/arp2.berlios/gg-libtool-1.4.2-1.i386.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/autotools/2002-03/autotools-for-ac.2.53.lt.1.4.2.am.1.6-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/autotools/2002-03/autotools-for-ac.2.53.lt.1.4.2.am.1.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/autotools/2002-03/autotools-for-ac.2.52.lt.1.4.am.1.4.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/autotools/2002-03/autotools-for-ac.2.52.lt.1.4.am.1.4-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/autotools/2002-03/autotools-for-ac.2.52.lt.1.4.2.am.1.6-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/autotools/2002-03/autotools-for-ac.2.52.lt.1.4.2.am.1.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/autotools/2002-03/autotools-for-ac.2.52.lt.1.4.2.am.1.4.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/autotools/2002-03/autotools-for-ac.2.52.lt.1.4.2.am.1.4-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/autotools/2002-03/autotools-for-ac.2.13.lt.1.4.am.1.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/autotools/2002-03/autotools-for-ac.2.13.lt.1.4.am.1.4-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/autotools/2002-03/autotools-for-ac.2.13.lt.1.4.2.am.1.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/autotools/2002-03/autotools-for-ac.2.13.lt.1.4.2.am.1.4.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/autotools/2002-03/autotools-for-ac.2.13.lt.1.4.2.am.1.4-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/OldFiles/autotools-ac.2.52d.lt.1.4b.am.1.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/OldFiles/autotools-ac.2.52d.lt.1.4.am.1.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/OldFiles/autotools-ac.2.52d.lt.1.4.am.1.4.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/OldFiles/autotools-ac.2.52d.lt.1.4.2.am.1.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/OldFiles/autotools-ac.2.52d.lt.1.4.2.am.1.4l-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/OldFiles/autotools-ac.2.52.lt.1.4b.am.1.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/OldFiles/autotools-ac.2.52.lt.1.4.am.1.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/OldFiles/autotools-ac.2.52.lt.1.4.am.1.4l-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/OldFiles/autotools-ac.2.52.lt.1.4.am.1.4.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/OldFiles/autotools-ac.2.52.lt.1.4.am.1.4-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/OldFiles/autotools-ac.2.52.lt.1.4.2.am.1.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/OldFiles/autotools-ac.2.52.lt.1.4.2.am.1.4f-2sfnet.i586.rpm
Other   ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/ac/ac-archive/OldFiles/autotools-ac.2.52.lt.1.4.2.am.1.4.5-2sfnet.i586.rpm
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer, however I've already tried that with the same outcome. I reinstalled the whole `libtool-ltdl` package but then, when trying to install the `Image::Magick` package, I get the dependencies issue.

Comment: what version is your copy of libtool-ltdl ? on rpm search it shows libltdl.so.3 in package                          CentOS 5  ftp.centos.org/5.9/os/x86_64/CentOS/libtool-ltdl-1.5.22-7.el5_4.x86_64.rpm                                             as well as the same version for i386

Comment: My currently installed version is `libtool-ltdl-2.2.6-15.5.el6.i686`

Comment: have listed the packages that have it maybe you can install that specific version at the same time if you have other dependences that need it. Check to see if you have an older version of Image Magick.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `yum install ImageMagick` should do (it is very unlikely that it was installed without the dependencies). If the system thinks the package is installed, `yum reinstall ImageMagick` is the command to run. If this gives trouble, `yum deplist ...` gives the list of packages providing dependencies.

Also install `yum-utils`, check at least the manual pages for `yum` and `package-cleanup`.